# converting tables into picture

Tags: tables, graphics, convert

After creating a table, I convert it into picture and then insert it as a graphics. I do this to force the table embedded in the place I want it to be there. Is there any disadvantage to do this? or it just funny?

I use this code:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper,twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\begin{document}
    \lipsum[1]
        .......ditunjukkan pada Tabel III.1 berikut:\\
    \begin{center}
        TABEL III.1 SHOULD BE HERE
    \end{center}
\begin{table}
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}{ccl}
        \hline 
        No. & Skor & Kategori \\
        \hline
        1 & 0,0 - 5,4 & Sangat Rendah \\
        2 & 5,5 - 6,4 & Rendah \\  
        3 & 6,5 - 7,4 & Sedang \\
        4 & 7,5 - 8,4 & Tinggi \\
        5 & 8,5 - 10  & Sangat Tinggi \\
        \hline
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}
\lipsum[1-2]
    .......ditunjukkan pada Tabel III.2 berikut:\\
\begin{center}
    TABEL III.2 SHOULD BE HERE
\end{center}
        \begin{table}
            \centering
            \begin{tabular}{llcc}
                \toprule
                Interval & Kategori & Jumlah Siswa & Persentase (\%)\\
                \midrule
                $ 81-100 $ & Sangat tinggi & 2 & 7,69\\
                $ 61-80 $ & Tinggi & 8 & 30,77 \\  
                $ 41-60 $ & Sedang & 9 & 34,62\\
                $ 21-40 $ & Rendah & 4 & 15,38\\
                $ \leqslant 20 $ & Sangat rendah & 3 & 11,54\\
                \bottomrule
            \end{tabular}
        \end{table}

\end{document}
```

but the tables going anywhere. so I use this:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper,twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
    \lipsum[1]
    .......ditunjukkan pada Tabel III.1 berikut:\\
\begin{center}
        TABEL III.1 SHOULD BE HERE
\end{center}
    \begin{center}
        Tabel III.1: Kriteria Hasil Belajar Mahasiswa
        \includegraphics[width=0.9\linewidth]{"C:/Users/Enos Lolang/Pictures/JKIP/Tabel 1 Lasarus"}
    \end{center}
\lipsum[1-2]
.........ditunjukkan pada Tabel III.2 berikut:\\
\begin{center}
    TABEL III.2 SHOULD BE HERE
\end{center}
\begin{center}
    Tabel III.2. Distribusi Frekuensi Skor Hasil Belajar Kalkulus II Mahasiswa Untuk Pendekatan Problem Posing Berkelompok
    \includegraphics[width=0.9\linewidth]{"C:/Users/Enos Lolang/Pictures/JKIP/Tabel 5 Lasarus"}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

Comment: There should be no reason why you can't get the table where you want directly, thus avoidng the unnecessary intermediate and costly step of graphic conversion.  Why don't you show us some code to explain exactly what you mean.?  Welcome to the site.

Comment: Use `\begin{table}[ht]` to invoke the tables, which directs LaTeX to attempt to place the tables at their place of invocation.  In general, `table`s are "floats", meaning that LaTeX chooses where it thinks best to locate them; the `h` specifier overrides the default guidance LaTeX uses.

Comment: instead `\begin{center}\includegraphics{<your table converted into graphics>}\end{center}` you can use `\begin{center}<your table code>\end{center}`. ... but what you will do, if the table will be greater than available space on page? I strongly encourage you to consider @StevenB.Segletes second comment.

Comment: @Steven B. Segletes: yes, the first table fixed. but the second table exceeds column in place, I try to use {table*}[ht] but the table moved to the next page. far away from it's name mentioned.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `\begin{table}[ht]` to invoke the tables, which directs LaTeX to attempt to place the tables at their place of invocation. In general, `table`s are "floats", meaning that LaTeX chooses where it thinks best to locate them; the `h` specifier overrides the default guidance LaTeX uses.

The fact that a table is too wide is not LaTeX's fault.  However, we can narrow it down with a combination of stacking column headings as well as decreasing `\tabcolsep`.

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper,twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{stackengine}
\begin{document}
    \lipsum[1]
        .......ditunjukkan pada Tabel III.1 berikut:\\
    \begin{center}
        TABEL III.1 SHOULD BE HERE
    \end{center}
\begin{table}[ht]
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}{ccl}
        \hline 
        No. & Skor & Kategori \\
        \hline
        1 & 0,0 - 5,4 & Sangat Rendah \\
        2 & 5,5 - 6,4 & Rendah \\  
        3 & 6,5 - 7,4 & Sedang \\
        4 & 7,5 - 8,4 & Tinggi \\
        5 & 8,5 - 10  & Sangat Tinggi \\
        \hline
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}
\lipsum[1-2]
    .......ditunjukkan pada Tabel III.2 berikut:\\
\begin{center}
    TABEL III.2 SHOULD BE HERE
\end{center}
        \begin{table}[ht]
          \tabcolsep=4pt\relax
            \centering
            \begin{tabular}{llcc}
                \toprule
                Interval & Kategori & \stackunder{Jumlah}{Siswa} & 
                  \stackunder{Persentase}{(\%)}\\
                \midrule
                $ 81-100 $ & Sangat tinggi & 2 & 7,69\\
                $ 61-80 $ & Tinggi & 8 & 30,77 \\  
                $ 41-60 $ & Sedang & 9 & 34,62\\
                $ 21-40 $ & Rendah & 4 & 15,38\\
                $ \leqslant 20 $ & Sangat rendah & 3 & 11,54\\
                \bottomrule
            \end{tabular}
        \end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: OK. @Steven B. Segletes, thank you very much.